# Is it possible to use queries within aggregate functions?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

Is the following acceptable in SQL:

```
SELECT P.pid P.cnt
FROM Professors P
WHERE P.cnt <= Max(SELECT P2.cnt FROM Professors P2)
```

I am asking because this is provided as an answer to a problem in a midterm by the professor. I have actually tried it in SQL and wasn't allowed, but I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntactically, I would have written it like this:

```
SELECT P.pid, P.cnt
  FROM Professors P
  WHERE P.cnt <= (SELECT MAX(P2.cnt) FROM Professors P2)
```

Logically, it doesn't really seem to accomplish much since the condition will always be true.

Comment: I didn't write the full query, I just used the problematic part in a dummy query :)

Answer (score 2):

This won't work. I don't think it is standard ANSI SQL

You can try to rewrite it like this

```
SELECT P.pid P.cnt
FROM Professors P
WHERE P.cnt <= (SELECT max(P2.cnt) FROM Professors P2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, queries are allowed within aggregate functions.  What was the error you got when you tried it?  The thing that sticks out to me is a missing comma after `P.pid` in `SELECT P.pid P.cnt`.

I may be missing something obvious myself, but to me, this seems like a bit of extra SQL that is doing nothing.  I read it as "Select information about Professsors for all Professors that are less than or equal to the Professor with the greatest count" - I.E., all professors.  Why not just eliminate the `WHERE` entirely?

Comment: You are quite right, this is just a dummy query I posted to get answers about the problematic bit.